# Deleting Object from Nested Array MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

I am trying to delete the object with the `id: "2019-08-22T04:53:11.357Z"` from this users `portfolio` array.

I have searched for the correct query filter to help me delete the object but nothing seems to be working!

Here is the data we are working with. There is currently only one user 
 (InStock) in the system but more will be added in the future.

```
[
  {
    "id": "MTg4MDU3ODM2MDk2NDU0NjU3",
    "name": "InStock",
    "balance": 7760,
    "portfolio": [
      {
        "id": "2019-08-22T04:15:22.998Z",
        "name": "Jordan Shoe",
        "size": "10.5",
        "price": 150
      },
      {
        "id": "2019-08-22T04:36:37.836Z",
        "name": "Nike Tee",
        "size": "M",
        "price": 35
      },
      {
        "id": "2019-08-22T04:53:11.357Z",
        "name": "Adidas Shoe",
        "size": "8.5",
        "price": 100
      }
    ],
    "history": [

    ]
  }
]
```

and here is what I was trying using what I've seen in other solutions.

```
db.collection(collectionName).updateOne({"id": "MTg4MDU3ODM2MDk2NDU0NjU3"}, {$pull : {"portfolio": {"id": "2019-08-22T04:36:37.836Z"}}})
```

I am looking for the line to remove the  Adidas Shoe object from InStock's portfolio array.

Comment: user portfolio array is a collection in mongo?

Comment: @AzzamAsghar No, the collection includes the entire JSON I included with my question. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Your query was correct though, the only difference is that you have wrong id there, it ends with 836, not with 357 as you state at the top of your question, can that be the issue? So you are removing the wrong one, and thinking that `$pull` does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
db.test1.updateOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5d5e7a291b761bfc0420e580")}, 
{$pull: {"portfolio": {"name": "Adidas Shoe"}}})
```

After execution:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e7a291b761bfc0420e580"),
    "portfolio" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "2019-08-22T04:15:22.998Z",
            "name" : "Jordan Shoe",
            "size" : "10.5",
            "price" : 150.0
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "2019-08-22T04:36:37.836Z",
            "name" : "Nike Tee",
            "size" : "M",
            "price" : 35.0
        }
    ],
    "name" : "InStock",
    "balance" : 7760.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Working Fine for you.

```
db.collection(collectionName).updateOne({"id": "MTg4MDU3ODM2MDk2NDU0NjU3"},
{ $pull: { portfolio: { $elemMatch: { id:"2019-08-22T04:36:37.836Z"} }},
```

Comment: Results in error ```MongoError: unknown top level operator: $eq```

Comment: @AbramKremer updated my answer please check hope it's working

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sadly, it is still not removing the object as hoped for. I'm beginning to wonder if the problem lies somewhere else in my project, but I'm doubtful since all other MongoDB commands are performing properly.

Comment: @AbramKremer  okay got it .which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: Verision 3.3.0.

Comment: it's my suggestion to update your mongodb version.currently i am using MongoDB server version: 4.0.10 and MongoDB shell version v4.0.10